# How to apply google playstore scrolling animation?

Tags: android, animation

How do I apply the new scrolling effect, shown in google play to my app? So basically i dont need the actionbar emerging/disappearing factor, but I want to scroll a page and have an imageview on top disappear first before the whole page begins to scroll. I also want the ImageView to emerge once I scroll up.

the animation can be seen here : 0:34-0:40

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQA5k8Ly4fk

thanks in advance!!

Comment: It's called Parallax Effect. Look at this category: http://android-arsenal.com/tag/70. Have many libraries that implement this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use this libray

https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar

See in Google Play:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar.demo